# Lectura desde consola de Matriz en C

Tags: array, c

He escrito este código para un matriz, todo esta bien al compilar, pero cuando voy a digitar el 3er valor se cierra.

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main (){


    int mat[5][6];

    for (int i=0 ; i<5; i++){
        for (int f=0; f<5; f++){
            printf ("Ingresa el valor que debe quedar en la posicion %d x %d \n\n", i, f);
            scanf ("%d %d", &mat[i][f]);
        }       
    }

    for (int a=0; a<5; a++){
        for (int c=0; c<0; c++){

            printf ("El valor de la matriz es \n\n %d", mat[a][c]);
        }

    }       

    return=0

}
```

Gracias por adelantado

Comment: Hola, ¿es el código correcto? La parte del `return` no debería compilar.

Comment: ojo que en 'for (int c=0; c<0; c++){ no se va a ejecutar nunca..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
scanf ("%d %d", &mat[i][f]);
```

Configuras `scanf` para leer dos valores pero solo usas uno de ellos... ¿A dónde te imaginas que va el segundo? se escribe en una posición aleatoria de la memoria...

Sustituye esa línea por

```
scanf ("%d", &mat[i][f]);
```

Otro error que tienen, como te han indicado por comentarios es este:

```
return=0
```

Por varias razones:

- La línea no termina en punto y coma
- `return` no es una variable, luego no admite asignaciones.

En este caso la línea debería lucir así:

```
return 0;
```

Comment: Gracias por la ayuda, como habrás notado soy nuevo en esto, me sirvió